# Possible to install VM in another VM?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

Currently I own an MacBookPro. For some reasons, I need to run Windows. So I installed Windows XP using VirtualBox (a free virtual machine). My questions is: Can my Windows XP (which run from my MacBook Pro) install another VM machine, which is VMplayer, then I want to install ubuntu in the VMPlayer?

(Yes, you may ask, why dont I install the Ubuntu (client and server) on my macbook virtualbox? Well, as I said earlier, for some specific reasons.)

Comment: Look at [this Thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine) over at Serverfault. Modern hardware (like current CPUs in Apple products) should be able to do such tricks, but it also depends on the Virtualization Software to support such functionality.

Comment: Yo dawg, I put a VM in your VM, so you can virtualize while you virtualize. (Sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 1):

This is definetely possible.

You might get diffrent resutls from diffrent tools though.

Furthermore be prepared that if you computer isn't really fast you might experience heavy lagging issue on your virtul virtual machine.

But otherwise the virtual machine will most likely run since itself will not see the diffrence in running on an actual machine or on another virtual one.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it, but I would think it depends in your specs. If you have a dual core, and give the VM 1 core, what does the VM's VM get? I would think it could be possible though.